# Matching 2 Columns across 2 worksheets and filling in information

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have 2 Worksheets

In worksheet 1 i have a bunch of information, but in column H I have numbers

I also have worksheet 2 and in this sheet, I have 2 columns

I want to compare column H in worksheet1 against Column A in worksheet2, if the two numbers match, I want to pull the data from Column B in sheet2 and paste it into the column I of the same row the data matched column H

if this makes any sense, I am not quite sure how to go about doing this in VBA as my skills severely lack in this language. Any help would be appreciated, especially with an explanation but ill take any help I can get.

I know this can be done with vlookup but I am trying to make a vba macro

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need a VBA macro to do this. In your column I, this simple formula will work: `=IF(H7=Sheet2!A7,Sheet2!B7,"")`. But if you want a macro for other reasons, just set up your ranges and compares like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareAndCopy()
    Dim col1 As Range
    Dim col2 As Range
    Dim col3 As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    '--- assumes data in each cell with no empty cells
    Set col1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown))
    Set col2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Set col3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1")

    '--- assumes empty cells in column and selects down to the last data cell
    'Set col1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1", Range("H1048576").End(xlUp))
    'Set col2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    'Set col3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1")

    For i = 1 To col1.Rows.Count
        If col1.Cells(i, 1).Value = col2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            col3.Cells(i, 1).Value = col2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```